# What would probably caused a '/' keep added behind url entered in address bar of browser? - symfony

Tags: url, symfony1, slash

Once I entered http://abc.def.com/something , it keep automatically added '/' slash behind it, and caused it could not be direct to correct page.

What would probably cause this happened? Would it be caused by routing file? or .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a rewrite rule in a .htaccess file or any other Apache config file.

Comment: oh thanks. I not too sure why the problem exists suddenly as I keep on doing it all the while. Previous day and one day before exists different page suddenly. Now it is ok already, could it be cache problem?